# how to copy an icloud coredata store to the app sandbox

Tags: core-data, icloud

Many issues with coredata & icloud are known. But I use it with a productive app on the appstore. Now I want to step back and would like to have a copy of my icloud database in the documents directory of my app.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Better could someone please setup a step by step guidance for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy the store from the iCloud. The iCloud does not work with a monolithic binary store, but with a series of update files in combination with a store.

So your best option is simply to create a new store in the documents directory, fetch all records and populate the new store like this. Don't forget to configure your app's core data stack to point to the new store instead.